# List comprehension to get rows from a dataframe that contains matching column values of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension, any

So I have 2 wildly different dataframes- different column names, different data.
Both have a column that contain some matching numbers. Ive attempted to use list comp with any() statements without success, and merge/join is a mess without renaming everything. heres a small example of what im working on:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5, 5)), columns=list('FGHIJ'))

match = [x for x in df1['B'] if any(y in x for y in df2['K'])]
df_match = df1[match]
```

This always gives me an output of all `True` values, or i get an empty list.
Sort of lost, just trying to get df1 rows where df1.B matches df2.K and require something as fast or faster than list comprehension for my massive dataset.

EDIT: I should add that these 'numbers' in the dataframes are all strings ('24').
I solved this problem a couple weeks ago before i lost my code, and i recall using a list comprehension with any() to get it to work but cannot recall what it was that i did syntactically ):

Comment: Does `df1[df1['B'].isin(df2['K'])]['B']` meet your need?

Comment: Thanks for the response, It just seems to return an empty df with all of the column names of df1

Comment: Are there shared values in the B and K columns? If you could show a sample dataframe that isn't randomly generated differently each time, and an expected output based on that input, that would help to provide a more useful answer

Comment: Yes, just going down the list and counting, i see a dozen or more in the first 60-70 numbers.

Comment: Using a boolean mask with the built in method `.isin()` is generally one of the more efficient ways to solve this problem. Are you sure that the values match? Are you sure they're not a number in one DF and a string in the other? This works in any test I run, for example `df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5],'b':[6,7,8,9,0]});df3 = pd.DataFrame({'c':[1,3,5,7,9],'d':[2,4,6,8,0]})` then `df2[df2['b'].isin(df3['d'])]` returns rows 0,2,4

Comment: thank you for continuing to respond! yes ive set both columns to strings with .astype(str), im worried now that something is wrong with my machine/notebook/kernel, its taking an almost instant 47ms to complete over 160k rows on a 30 column dataframe and returning the same empty df. here is my current code df_match=df1[df1['b'].isin(df2['k'])], then df_match.head()

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you actually meant to write was

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(10, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(10, 5)), columns=list('EFGHI'))
```

Since my dfs have a shared column we know what we are looking for to agree and since the values are 0 and 1 they are likely to agree from time to time :).

Now

```
df1["E"]==df2["E"]
```

gives you a series of true und false values. That is true if the dfs agree in column e and false otherwise. Now if you want the rows where that's the case you do
`df1[df1["E"]==df2["E"]]` or `df2[df1["E"]==df2["E"]].` If you want to combine the dfs you have to reset the index and join them like this

```
df1[df1["E"]==df2["E"]].reset_index(drop=True)\
.join(df2[df1["E"]==df2["E"]].reset_index(drop=True)[["F","G","H"]])
```

Notice that I had to get rid of column E in df2 since it overlapped.

Since that seems to be the case in the actual problem here a version with differently named columns:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(10, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(10, 5)), columns=list('FGHIJ'))


df1[df1["E"]==df2["E"]].reset_index(drop=True)\
.join(df2[df1["E"]==df2["F"]].reset_index(drop=True)[["G","H","I"]])
```

Notice that with `[["G","H","I"]]` I have dropped the column F from df2 before joining since it would be redundant information. By choice of the rows columns E and F must contain exactly the same information.

Comment: So my columns are actually labeled differently. In this situation i cannot change the column names without breaking other parts of my script, I could rename but it wouldnt be the best. I solved this before and lost my code when VM was deleted. I used List Comprehension with an any() statement im almost sure of it but cant recall what it was that i did.

Comment: That's no problem I will add a version of that.